# Issue discerning accepted answer for a colour blind person

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface, accepted-answer

Couple of days ago I was discussing Stack Overflow website with a person who was colour blind.

He complained about [Top Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/) screen that he couldn't discern questions with accepted answer from the questions where an answer has not been accepted yet. For him the yellow font on green-ish background was not good enough.

So in order to improve his (and other colour blind uses of SO site) experience, I thought it would be worth considering adding some additional markers on questions with accepted answers on the [Top Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [All Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) screens.

A few proposals:

[image: Accepted Answer Proposal]
[image: Accepted Answer Proposal Alternative]

Comment: The marking on many other SE sites is far better than on SO/MSO, SO and MSO being horrible in a usability perspective (in that regard). Something needs to change, indeed. =)

Comment: Personally I found the second proposal horrible but doing nothing wouldn't be acceptable. An improved version of the first proposal would be great.